# Cordova plugin Datepicker popup, displayed in wrong position on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, cordova, datepicker

We got a Cordova project (3.6.3), and (for various reasons I don't want to discuss here) we had to include date picker plugin from here:
https://github.com/sectore/phonegap3-ios-datepicker-plugin.
All's fine on iPhones,but iPad brings weird behaviour to the table  [image: datepicker plugin issue]

So firstly - it doesn't remove native date picker, when I'm clicking on a label of date input field (it does remove it when I click on input itself).
Secondly - it displays plugin date picker in wrong place of viewport (top-left corner, instead of just above the date input field, as the native one).

Does anyone ever run into such problems, perhaps you know what is causing such weird behaviour of plugin?

Cheer

Comment: Did you ever find a work around for this?  I'm running into the same issue but with a newer version of the datepicker plugin.  I see in the documentation that it supports an X and Y config, but that is only for absolutely positioning the picker relative to the root view of the application, not directly beneath the picker.

Comment: If I remember well, we ended up in resorting to native date picker. So can't really help with this. It looks like in this particular case, for some reason, we were never cancelling native date picker, but I never get to the bottom of this problem, as it has "solved itself" out ;)

Answer (score 0):

About This issue you can display date picker of iPhone

let's see in code 
first in this function you need to comment special case for iphone to make it general case as written

```
(void)show:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command {
    _command = command;
  NSMutableDictionary *options = [command argumentAtIndex:0];
  //if (isIPhone) {
    [self showForPhone: options];
  //} else {
   // [self showForPad: options];
  //}
}
```

and don't forget to remove special handling for hiding also

```
(void)hide {
  //if (isIPhone) {
    CGRect frame = CGRectOffset(self.datePickerComponentsContainer.frame,
                                0,
                                self.datePickerComponentsContainer.frame.size.height);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:ANIMATION_DURATION
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{
                       self.datePickerComponentsContainer.frame = frame;
                       self.datePickerContainer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0];

                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                       [self.datePickerContainer removeFromSuperview];
                     }];

 // } else {
  //  [self.datePickerPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
 // }
}
```